# How to avoid subquery, CTE and stored procedure

Tags: sql, subquery

This is a test on job interview.

There are two tables:

**films**

```
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
```

**film_actors**

```
film_id INT,
actor_id INT,
fee INT,
UNIQUE (film_id, actor_id), INDEX (actor_id)
```

It is needed to return film names in order of appearance highly paid actors in it.

1. It needs to find the sum(fee) each actor gets -> this forms the list of actors salary.
2. And then per each film it's needed to summarize the salary of all actors involved in it -> this will give the needed result.

The data example below:

```
INSERT INTO films (id, name)
VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'D');

INSERT INTO film_actors (film_id, actor_id, fee)
VALUES (1, 1, 1000), (1, 2, 500), (1, 3, 3000),
       (2, 1, 500), (2, 4, 1000), (2, 5, 600),
       (3, 6, 1000), (3, 3, 100), (3, 7, 1000),
       (4, 5, 1100), (4, 7, 1200), (4, 3, 900);
```

The needed result will be: D, C, A, B

It's possible to get the result via subquery:

```
select
    name
from
    films
join 
    film_actors on film_actors.film_id = films.id
join  
    (select
         actor_id,
         sum(fee) as total_actor_fee
     from 
         film_actors 
     group by 
         actor_id) as total_actor_fees on total_actor_fees.actor_id = film_actors.actor_id
group by 
    1
order by 
    sum(total_actor_fee) desc
```

But I have no idea how to avoid the subquery or avoid CTE and stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

An answer came from employer:

```
SELECT f.name
FROM films AS f
INNER JOIN film_actors AS fa1 ON fa1.film_id = f.id
INNER JOIN film_actors AS fa2 ON fa2.actor_id = fa1.actor_id
GROUP BY f.id
ORDER BY SUM(fa2.fee) DESC;
```

Comment: What's the DBMS you're using(can you tag it please)? The respond might differ as each DBMS has different dialects.